# How get time on timecurrent on node of Firebase using Angular?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show only the time on the view, when use `$firebaseArray` I get the list of items and i want to get only the time.

Firebase tree

```
{
  "eventmodel" : {
    "-KX6kDkufxLg-fLocsN7" : {
      "info" : "ok",
      "limit" : 2,
      "timeCurrentStart" : "29/11/2016 17:38",
    },
    "-KXBB-R7xAPl65xhlTpg" : {
      "info" : "ok",
      "limit" : 2,
      "timeCurrentStart" : "29/11/2016 17:38",
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase client always retrieves complete nodes. There is no way to get only the `timeCurrentStart` property of each node.

So either you'll have to store the `timeCurrentStart` properties in a separate node:

```
{
  "eventmodeltimes" : {
    "-KX6kDkufxLg-fLocsN7" : "29/11/2016 17:38",
    "-KXBB-R7xAPl65xhlTpg" : "29/11/2016 17:38"
  }
}
```

Or you'll have to retrieve the entire nodes and only show `timeCurrentStart`:

```
<span>{{event.timeCurrentStart}}</span>
```